# Error in update function for CRUD in Windows Form

Tags: c#, ms-access

Am new to programming, so please assist as much as possible!
Recently, im tasked to do a CRUD windows form application using C# & MS access.

In my update function, i face one of the following errors which im not sure why..
My data are not able to be updated either.

Error: `ArgumentException` was unhandled

> Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store
>    in staff_id Column.  Expected type is
>   Int32.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AcuzioSapp.AcuzioSecureStore_DatabaseDataSetTableAdapters;

namespace AcuzioSapp
{
    public partial class Update_Client : Form
    {
        private DataRow row;
        private ClientTableAdapter adapter;
        public Update_Client(DataRow row, ClientTableAdapter adapter)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.row = row;
            this.adapter = adapter;
            textBox_id1.Text = Convert.ToString(row["c_id"]);
            textBox_name1.Text = Convert.ToString(row["c_name"]);
            textBox_address1.Text = Convert.ToString(row["c_address"]);
            textBox_cinfo1.Text = Convert.ToString(row["c_contactinfo"]);
            textBox_pinfo1.Text = Convert.ToString(row["profile_info"]);
            textBox_refno1.Text = Convert.ToString(row["c_8digitrefno"]);
            textBox_staffid1.Text = Convert.ToString(row["staff_id"]);
        }

        private void button_close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void button_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            row["c_name"] = "textBox_name1";
            row["c_address"] = "textBox_address1";
            row["c_contactinfo"] = "int.Parse(textBox_cinfo1)";
            row["c_8digitrefno"] = "(textBox_pinfo1)";
            row["profile_info"] = "textBox_refno1";
            row["staff_id"] = "int.Parse(textBox_staffid1)";

            adapter.Update(row);
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciated for help and explanation thankyou.

Comment: Which line gives you this error? Did you debug your code?

Comment: Yes i did. the row["staff_id"] = "int.Parse(textBox_staffid1)"; and row["c_contactinfo"] = "int.Parse(textBox_cinfo1)"; line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because of your column is declared integer in your Access database and you try to insert a String value in it. And I also think you will not get proper value in your specified table because you update your columns by constant string `(row["profile_info"] = "textBox_refno1";)`, this will insert **textBox_refno1** into `profile_info` column not TextBox value. 
Try this :

```
row["staff_id"] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox_staffid1.Text);
```

**Update:**
Copy and paste following code, and you will never have any issue:

```
    private void button_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        row["c_name"] = textBox_name1.Text;
        row["c_address"] = textBox_address1.Text;
        row["c_contactinfo"] = int.Parse(textBox_cinfo1.Text);
        row["c_8digitrefno"] = textBox_pinfo1.Text;
        row["profile_info"] = textBox_refno1.Text;
        row["staff_id"] = int.Parse(textBox_staffid1.Text);

        adapter.Update(row);

        MessageBox.Show("Data has been updated");
    }
```

Hope this help.

Comment: ah, i followed what you said and got this error. "Cannot implicitly convert type int to type string.

Comment: Still can't, same error still. Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <Convert.ToInt32(textBox_staffid1.Text)> in staff_id Column.  Expected type is Int32.

Comment: Remove all double quotations right side of equal operator. You are inserting a constant string instead of Textbox values.

Comment: row["staff_id"] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox_staffid1.Text); - i think i should remove the .text cause when i include it, the datagridview displays the staffid1.text string instead of the value in the database

Comment: Yes it works! Thank you so much. Ah last question, how do i add a message box after clicking update to prompt that data has been successfully updated?

Comment: Thankyou so much. Been so much of a help

Answer (score 0):

```
        row["c_name"] = textBox_name1.Text;
        row["c_address"] = textBox_address1.Text;
        ...
        int val;
        if(int.TryParse(textBox_staffid1.Text, out val))
        {
             row["staff_id"] = val;
        }
```

I consider, that text in your textbox not in correct format.

Comment: Changed but am still facing the same error, Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <int.Parse(textBox_staffid1.Text)> in staff_id Column.  Expected type is Int32.